# Why does Stack Overflow think I live in the Netherlands?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Or why does Google?

If I open the "create a CV" link, my name shows - correct - and location "Netherlands" (powered by Google) - funny, I have never been there - and most of the job offers I get are for the Netherlands. Why?

This is a good example of (mis)using wrong data. I'm asking for a discussion because the pre-filled-in data is  just *wrong*.

SO is probably working with wrong data on its "job beta". I came to this forum because the SO feedback button brought me here.

edit: add information based on answer:

a trace route and a whois shows the the first 4 hops are within OTE Net GR

```
netname:        OTE
descr:          HELLENIC TELECOMMUNICATIONS ORGANIZATION
country:        GR
```

the IPadress i have: is in this range:
whois:

```
inetnum:        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
netname:        OTENET
descr:          located in Greece and having nodes in 63 cities
country:        GR
```

a "where am i" puts me (my computer) at least on the correct island

and last but not least:

```
a simple google.com redirects me to https://www.google.gr
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Aren't you capable of supplying that information to Jobs?

Comment: @Makoto: me, too. I am capable to supply that information. at least most times. *gg*. I ask for discussion, because SO works with wrong data, and it is already filled out for me

Comment: Is the form editable?  What's stopping you from adjusting it?  No geolocation service is ever going to be perfect unless they were capable of sticking a GPS fob to your leg...

Comment: @Makoto: please dont miss hear me: SO works with wrong data, prob paying for that. that is a BETA service, I want to give feedback

Comment: Do you access SO via proxies/TOR at all? I am assuming that it picks up your location from the location of the IP addresses you use.

Comment: @ChrisF: just no, I am an old man with computers, and was involved in computer ferensic, nothing fits here - its just wrong

Comment: What's your actual point and/or question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe:   as edit#2: I just wanted to feedback SO that they are working with (and probably paying) for wrong data

Comment: Let's check a few things: The location field was never entered by you before this? Although you're not in the Netherlands, are you on main land europe?

Comment: For the record, being geolocated in the Netherlands if you're actually in Greece *is* weird. Not sure how that can happen.

Comment: @Pekka웃: 100%, thats it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: not me; SO does, probably - I do not pay for any data

Comment: Edit to clarify or don't bother, but please don't just whine.

Comment: I'm not sure why a simple bug report needs to be closevoted and downvoted this much. We have had lots of Careers geolocation bug reports and they were all received very well.

Comment: @Pekka웃: I dont know ether. may be "It cant be?"

Comment: @Pekka웃 I guess because the question doesn't come across as a geolocation bug report. If it said "SO thought I'm in another country, please fix", there probably wouldn't be an issue. I have to admit that I was also a bit taken aback by the wording of the question, though I can't put my finger on exactly what's wrong. Maybe that despite its short length, the question still manages to seem quite digressive (again, just my impression). I also wouldn't assume that SO has anything to do with a mistaken geolocation problem, but that's just my view of the world:)

Comment: A [meta-tag:bug-report] tag would probably also help.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: its not a bug - and not a problem with geolocation. just wrong data.

Comment: It seems that you're making a lot of assumptions about how the system works. How can you be certain that it is not a bug with the geolocation service?

Comment: @TinyGiant: I asked just why SO thinks that I am around Netherlands. and I know, that I am not there -> data wrong. And since 'powered by google' is written near wrong data, I was even more surprised. (because adds I get in elinika).

Comment: @rene. sry overseen your comment: no i never filled that field and I am not on main land europe; I am on an island in EU/europe

Comment: They of course cannot know that you live on a small island if you don't volunteer that information.  Their first guess comes from your IP address.  So high odds that your local ISP bought access to the Internet through a Dutch company.  Common enough, Amsterdam is a major backbone hub.  Give them a call to make sure.

Comment: This question probably should be asked on webmasters or maybe SO - than when halbit figures out whether it is a problem with SO geolocation or just strangeness of network routing it can be brought back as "SO bug". I don't yet see how it can be answered on META.

Comment: Close-voting as _"This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."_, since the incorrectly supplied geolocation is not something SO can fix. It's an ISP problem.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with SO *"(mis)using wrong data"*

Geolocation works by looking at your IP address. If that address somehow resolves to a different country than you're in, your ISP is to blame.
SO can't possibly know the provided location is incorrect. There is no way SO can "Fix" this.

You're just going to have to manually enter the correct location.

Comment: As they are using the Google GEO location api they could probably get a better location if they didn't only use the IP address but also the phonenumber and/or the local  GPS  device. But that would require them to collect more PII then they or we as users probably want.

Comment: @rene well, the [ios app asks geo data already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271200/213575)

Comment: @Braiam: That geo data doesn't include a phone number. I wouldn't be surprised if the google geolocation api requested local GPS device access, already.

Comment: @Cerbrus I was responding to "the local GPS device" of rene's comment